# Alternatives on Ubuntu

Tags: windows, video, alternative

This is not question about how Linux works or something similar. I just want ask if is there some similar application like Xilisoft Video Converter and Sony Vegas Pro 10. Because I need an application, where I can edit a video, add subtitles, convert and more. And something like Vegas Pro for editing videos (like cutting, color edits, add music and other). Thanks.

Edit: + software like notepad++

Answer (score 1):

[Avidemux](http://avidemux.sourceforge.net/) is a free video editor designed for simple cutting, filtering and encoding tasks. It supports many file types, including AVI, DVD compatible MPEG files, MP4 and ASF, using a variety of codecs.<sup>Avidemux</sup>

To install you can also click [**Avidemux** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/search/?q=Avidemux&op=).

Video Editing program [OpenShot](http://www.openshotvideo.com/) Features include: Support for many video, audio, and image formats (based on FFmpeg), Gnome integration (drag and drop support), and Multiple tracks.<sup>OpenShot</sup>

To install you can also click [**OpenShot** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/openshot/).

[Lightworks](http://www.lwks.com/) is an editing powerhouse, delivering unparalleled speed and flexibility, fully integrated with the other members of the Complete Collaboration family.<sup>Lightworks</sup>

As far as Notepad++, you can use sCiTE.  SciTE is available in apt repository of Ubuntu. To install it just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install scite
```

To convert Video, take a look at:

[HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is an open-source, multithreaded video transcoder- it converts digital media from one format to another, compressing the files in the process.<sup>HandBrake</sup>

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for a software where I put the videos (3-5 videos) add srt and press convert and everything go automatically. I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative 1** to Xilisoft Video Converter: I always do my conversion on the command line with `ffmpeg` as it's fast and effective. There is a bit of a learning curve, however there are numerous front ends available for ease of use several of which are mentioned here: https://github.com/amiaopensource/ffmpeg-amia-wiki/wiki/3)-Graphical-User-Interface-Applications-using-FFmpeg

**Alternative 2** Another powerful video editor that is an alternative to Sony Vegas Pro  (open source) is [cinelerra.](http://cinelerra.org/)

**Alternative 3** There are several good alternatives for programming editors like notepad++. Ive used both `gedit` and `scite` (both of which are available via the software center) and found them both to be quite satisfactory.

Note: To install SciTE you'll need to [enable the universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) first.